# Dotted list in lisp

Tags: list, lisp, cons

I'm trying to recreate this structure with lisp `(key . (list of values))`

Ex: `(a . (b c))`

I managed to recreate the opposite `((a b) . c)`, but is not what i need.
Is possible?

Comment: That's not an association list. Association lists look like `((key . val) (key . val) ...)`

Comment: Is there anyway to implement that structure in list?

Comment: Of course, you can implement any list structure. Just don't call it an association list if it's not associating keys with values.

Comment: Thanks, i think an implementation could be using a simple list

Comment: Is this supposed to be an element of an a-list, where `a` is the key and `(b c)` is the value?

Comment: Yes, i want A as Key and (b c) as value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(cons 'a (list 'b 'c))
```

Note that when you print this it will be printed as

```
(A B C)
```

because a cons whose cdr is a list is printed using list notation, not dotted notation.

Comment: I need the dot after the a value

Comment: Why? It's the same data. If you need it printed a certain way, write your own code to format it.

Comment: A thanks, i thought there's a way to print the list like that, without formatting the output

Comment: @Void Basically `'(1 2 3)` and `'(1 . (2 . (3 . ())))` creates the exact same structure and the repl and `display` can only represent the same data in one way. Which one would you prefer for lists? Thus Scheme has rules that in the event the `cdr` is a `pair?` or `null?` you can omit the paren by removing the dot in the visualization. When you've worked enough with lists so that you know how to pick out `y` in `((a b) (s (d y))` you almost see the missing parens and dots though.